# What does the mode= argument of download.file do?

Tags: r

This is the second time that I searched online for help with download.file and solved my problem by calling the mode argument but I don't know what is the reason or when/why to use them.  Just saw the suggestion and passed the argument to get my problem solved.

The R help file on download.file() is a bit too brief and dose not tell me when to use particular mode

> mode   character. The mode with which to write the file. Useful values are
>   "w", "wb" (binary), "a" (append) and "ab". Only used for the "internal"
>   method. (See also ‘Details’.)

For me to get correct answer I had to pass the mode="wb" below; but why (maybe something to do with the s in https or should i just go with trial and error for now).

```
fileUrl <-"https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fjeff.jpg"
download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "./data/leekjpg.jpg", mode="wb")
```

I would like get at least some rudimentary understanding of the method and mode argument in download.file and would appreciate your explanations or suggestive reads.

I am downloading more files, and it bothers me that I don't know when to pass some the related arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the docs say:

> If mode is not supplied and url ends in one of .gz, .bz2, .xz, .tgz,
>   .zip, .rda or .RData a binary transfer is done. Since Windows (unlike
>   Unix-alikes) does distinguish between text and binary files, care is
>   needed that other binary file types are transferred with mode = "wb".
>   unix A progress bar tracks the transfer. If the file length is known,
>   an equals sign represents 2% of the transfer completed: otherwise a
>   dot represents 10Kb. Code written to download binary files must use
>   mode = "wb", but the problems incurred by a text transfer will only be
>   seen on Window

Basically it is saying that `"w"` and `"wb"` are the same when using on Unix-like OS, because they do not differentiate between text and binary files, but Windows does.

In Windows the line endings are slightly different. To be safe I use "w" when opening text files, where as `"wb"` when files are not supposed to be text, like `jpg`

Comment: Thanks for my purposes, your advice coupled with what is here: https://rpubs.com/thoughtfulbloke/downloadtips